# Joomla 2.5 - Plugin for Plugin

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Let's say I want to change the behaviour of some component (just add some scripts and styles to back-end and front-end). Is it possible to do it from other plugin without changing the code of the target component?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible. You just should make sure that your plugin is executed after the one you'd like to "modify"...